# Sinusoidal Wave Terminology

Tags: terminology

Suppose I have a sinusoidal signal of the form $x(t) = a\sin\left(2\pi b(t-c)\right) + d$.  I understand $a$ is the amplitude, $b$ is the wave number, and $c$ is the phase shift.  I know that the term $d$ shifts the entire signal vertically, but does it have a specific name in signal processing?

Answer (score 1):

It is usually called *DC offset* or *DC component*. Since you use $t$ as a variable, which suggests "time", the quantity $b$ would normally be called *frequency*. Also note that $c$ is not the phase but a time offset. The phase $\phi$ is usually defined as in

$$x(t)=A\sin(2\pi ft+\phi)\tag{1}$$

Comparing (1) to your formula gives $\phi=-2\pi bc$.

Comment: Ah yes!  I keep forgetting that the terminology changes if the variable is time vs space, even though the form is equivalent mathematically.